# Selenium changing order of html tags in page_source object

Tags: python, html, selenium

I was writing a regular expression to capture some text from a page_source object returned by Selenium and noticed the following strange behavior. The page returned by Selenium, whether I am logged in or not, contains the following HTML string:

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> driver = webdriver.Firefox()
>>> driver.get(url)
>>> selenium_page = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8')
>>> print selenium_page
...
<a href="http://www.meetup.com/Russian-Brooklyn/" title="Meetup Group: The 4th Ave Brooklyn Russian Language Meetup Group" class="omnCamp omngj_pcg4">
...
```

However, if I click "View page source" in the browser window opened by Selenium, the equivalent line looks like this:

```
<a class="omnCamp omngj_pcg4" title="Meetup Group: The 4th Ave Brooklyn Russian Language Meetup Group" href="http://www.meetup.com/Russian-Brooklyn/">
```

What's going on here?

Thanks

Comment: Theoretically, the order is not important and any sequence can be used. Why is it important for you? Please describe the use case. Thanks.

Comment: Writing robust regular expressions.

Comment: Why parse HTML with regex in the first place? - `selenium` itself is good at locating elements and extracting attribute values. If selenium doesn't fit, use an HTML parser, like `BeautifulSoup`.

Comment: Anyway, you should not rely on the attribute order.

Comment: Trying to avoid more dependencies, and curious about the behavior. Is BS good at capturing the contents of an html tag (ie, what's between < and >, not > and <)?